# TypeError: player_attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I keep on getting this error and I have absolutely no idea why, I have 3 files importing information from each other however this main one only draws information from monster_01.py and its player.py.

```
TypeError: player_attack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

---main code---

```
'''Player class
Fall 2014
@author Myles Taft (mbt6)
'''

import random
import monster_01



class Player():

    def __init__(self, strength = 0, player_hp = 0):
        self.strength = 1
        self.player_hp = 100
        print(self.strength, self.player_hp)

    def battle():



        def player_attack(self):
            print('success')
            while self.enemy_hp > 0:
                monster_01()
                self.dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                self.dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
                self.dice_sum = dice1 + dice2
                self.attack = dice1 + dice2
                self.decide_roll = input('Type "roll" to roll the dice:')
                self.roll = print('First die:' + dice1, 'Second die:' + dice2, 'Sum of dice:' + dice_sum)

                if self.roll == 2 or 4 or 6 :
                    print('Hit!')
                    self.enemy_hp == strength
                    print(enemy_hp)
                elif self.roll == 1 or 3 or 5:
                    print('Miss!')

        def player_block(self):
            self.dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
            self.dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
            self.decide_roll = input('Type "roll" to roll the dice:')
            self.roll = print('First die:' + dice1, 'Second die:' + dice2, 'Sum of dice:' + dice_sum)

            if self.roll == 2 or 4:
                print('Blocked!')
                self.player_hp -= int((enemy_strength)/2)
            if self.roll == 1 or 3:
                self.player_hp -= int(enemy_strength)

        def choice(self):
            get_player_attack(get_player_attack)
            self.player_choice = input('Do you attack or block?') #self.player_hp, self.strength)
            if self.player_choice == 'attack':
                self.player_attack()
            elif self.player_choice == 'block':
                self.player_block()


        def get_player_attack(self):
            player_attack()



        choice(choice)




Player.battle()
```

I've been up and down this code a hundred times, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `choice(choice)` is calling the class method with the class method as the parameter. Just do `choice()`. Self is an argument that is set behind the scenes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `get_player_attack` method:

```
def get_player_attack(self):
    player_attack()
```

It calls `player_attack` as if it were a stand-alone function and not another method.  But `player_attack` *is* a method of the class `Player` and therefore may only be called on an instance of `Player`.

The function should be called like:

```
self.player_attack()
```

---

Also, stuff like this:

```
if self.roll == 2 or 4 or 6 :
```

is just a problem waiting to happen.  It should be written as:

```
if self.roll in (2, 4, 6):
```

Otherwise, the condition of the if-statement will be interpreted as:

```
if (self.roll == 2) or (4) or (6):
```

which will always evaluate to `True`.  For more information, see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

---

Finally, you should not be putting all of your methods inside another function named `battle`.  I don't know what you are *trying* to do here, but method definitions should be just under the class header:

```
class MyClass:          # Class header
    def method1(self):  # Definition of the first method
        ...

    def method2(self):  # Definition of the next method
        ...
    ...
```

I really think it would be good for you to read some tutorials on Python classes and OOP.  Here are some to get you started:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: I think there's a bigger problem here. None of these things are actually methods; they're all local functions defined inside `battle`. So, just adding `self.` is just going to get a different exception.

Comment: I didn't notice that until after I posted.  I really don't know what the OP is trying to do with `battle`, so I'll just point out the problem.

Comment: Well, your answer now covers the first problem the OP is running into and what look like the next two problems he's most likely to face, so… hard to beat that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do within battle().  You haven't defined a `self` parameter, but neither have you used the @static decorator to indicate you want it to be a static function.  You've defined player_attack within battle, so it can't be an instance method.  The syntax is incorrect.

If you meant battle() to be an instance method, add a self parameter and provide a method body or pass, then make player_attack de-indented.